# xamarin android Plugin.XF.AppInstallHelper

Tags: xamarin.android

what is the equivalent to:

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

in a plain Xamarin Android App?

Comment: You can use `public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity` in Xamarin Android, What is your problem when you use `Plugin.XF.AppInstallHelper`?

Comment: Are there any update for this issue?